# SQL Query - Calculating Previous Year Sales

Tags: sql

I don't know anything about SQL. I currently have a query that gives me this. Sales for some products by channel/etc (please note this is a very simplified version, there's more fields) by week/period/year: 
[image]

Basically what I would need is to add a column that gives me the sales for prior year. Basically, transform the table as below. In Excel it would be a simple sumifs that would just sum the same exact criteria aside from the year which would be the previous year.

Is it possible to do this within SQL? The dataset is too large to do it within Excel.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       lag(sales) over (partition by channel, product, weekno order by yearno) as prev_sales
from t;
```

If I understand the data, then `periodno` is redundant with `weekno`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. If LAG can somehow figure out that 201718 is the year prior to 201819 which in turn is the year prior to 201920, it may be feasible. Ultimately each prior year can be seen as the following year minus 101. If I posted the query tomorrow, would you be able to add the code in? As I said I know nothing about SQL I'm afraid

Comment: @robeambro . . . I see no problem with that.  Whether it is a string or a number, 201718 is one unit before 201819.  I can't imagine a year value in-between them.